# C++ how to convert char array to vector of bytes (vector<byte>)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, type-conversion

I have large array of char

```
char myCharArray[] = {
  0x9B,0x3E,0x34,0x87,0xFD,0x24,0xB4,0x64,0xBA,0x80,0x04,0xFD,
  0xDF,0x23,0x41,0xEE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xAC,0xF9,0x8F,0x00,
  ...
}
```

How to convert **myCharArray** to `vector<byte>`

Comment: Just literally replace `char myCharArray[]` with `std::vector<byte> myCharArray` (or whatever name). Problem solved - if by "convert" you mean change type of your variable.

Comment: Or write `std::vector<char> v(std::begin(myCharArray), std::end(myCharArray));` and it'll copy the contents itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to inspect an array of `char` as an array of `std::byte`. So the most efficient solution would be:

```
#include <iterator> // for std::begin / end

std::vector<std::byte> v(
    reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(std::begin(myCharArray)), 
    reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(std::end(myCharArray))
);
```

This way, the vector knows up front how much memory to allocate and it can perform the copy via memcpy or a similar efficient routine instead of copying one byte after the other and having to reallocate multiple times in between.

EDIT:
Note that this code only works, because the return type of `std::begin` on a native array is guaranteed to be apointer. If `myCharArray` was e.g. a `std::vector<char>`, then `std::begin/end` would return an iterator (which may or may not be a native pointer). In that case, you would e.g. need to use `myCharVector.data()` and `myCharVector.data() + myCharVector.size()` to get pointers to the start and end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::byte> bytes;
for (char &c : myCharArray) {
    bytes.push_back(static_cast<std::byte>(c));
}
```